# Laravel Controller returning wrong view

Tags: laravel, controller

Why is Laravel Controller returning the "index" view instead of the "show" view when the form is submitted?

I'm using Laravel 9.38.0

HTML

```
<form action="jobs" id="form-job-search" method="GET">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" name="what" placeholder="Job" required>
  <input type="text" name="where" placeholder="City" required>
  <input type="submit" id="button-job-search" value="Find Jobs">
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/jobs', [JobController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/jobs/{what}/{where}', [JobController::class, 'show']);
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JobController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {
    return view('jobs.index');
  }

  public function show($what, $where) {
    return view('jobs.show');
  }
}
```

Comment: `action="jobs"` You're submitting the form on the same URL. The `what` and `where` inputs aren't magically mapped to `/{what}/{where}`, when you submit the form, the URL would be `/jobs?what=something&where=something`, but those are Query String parameters, not URL parameters. You should decide if you need to use `/{what}/{where}` as `$what` and `$where`, and add some logic on form submit to redirect to that URL, or if you can use the same URL and just do `$what = $request->input('what')` and `$where = $request->input('where')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this
Form

```
<form action="{{url('jobs')}}" id="form-job-search" method="post">
```

// here form content

Route change to
from

```
Route::get('/jobs/{what}/{where}', [JobController::class, 'show']);
```

to

```
Route::post('jobs', [JobController::class, 'show']);
```

Controller

```
 public function show(Request $request) {
    $what=$request->what;
    $where=$request->where;
    return view('jobs.show');
  }
```